# how to connect phonegap ajax url to spring mvc webserver

Tags: html, ajax, cordova

Hi i am getting  `No **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header is present on the requested resource` when i am hitting spring  `URL` using ajax call

any once can help me to resolve this ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust on your server side, not inside your app. Even you using JSONP, it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

in web service, just add the    **@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")**

for crossbrowser service call requires access.